# Where is AWS Backup stored?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-backup

I'm currently thinking about a backup concept for data stored in AWS S3. The data needs to stay in Germany, hence the `eu-central-1` region. As it should cover natural desasers as well (e.g. a fire in Frankfurt), the backup may not be physically close stored.

I couldn't find any data on where AWS Backup stores the backups. Are they stored in S3?

I know that every region has at least two "availability zones", but I couldn't find clear information where the actual server centers are. Is it even possible to configure this for the S3 bucket / the backup?

Comment: When I worked for a geospacial firm a while ago we had about 90PB of data.  Where would that get backed up to?  It all stays on S3.  There are 3 availability zones in Frankfurt. That implies that there are 3 physically separated data centers. If you can't leave Germany (i.e. the Milan or Paris regions are not possible) then you need to accept the three AZ setup. The data will be distributed between the AZ's as long as you're not using the "S3 One Zone-IA" S3 storage class.

Answer (score 1):

It is [stored across multiple availability zones](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/disaster-recovery-resiliency.html), [just like S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/disaster-recovery-resiliency.html).

Comment: Is that achieved by basically storing the backup in S3 (internally, by AWS)? In other words: Does the AWS Backup service make use of S3 internally?

Comment: It is probably achieved by storing it on the same backend that S3 is built on. It might be using S3 directly. You would have to ask an AWS employee (like your account rep) for those type of details, instead of asking on here.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Backups for S3 will be stored in S3, but you can configure it to be out-of-region. Be aware that these backups [will not be point-in-time restorable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/whatisbackup.html)

Depending on your use-case, it might make sense to take a look at an air gap solution like Clumio or Druva. You can store backups locally in a dedicated customer arena that's isolated outside of your enterprise access controls. They also allow you to recover your data from an exact point in time.